# For how many points X in the plane is it true that XA and XB are both positive integer distances, each less than or equal to 10?

Tags: geometry

> Consider a coordinate plane with the points A(-5,0) and B(5,0). For how many points X in the plane is it true that XA and XB are both positive integer distances, each less than or equal to 10?

Assume the location of X is (a,b), then $$XA=\sqrt{(a+5)^2+b^2}≤ 10$$  $$XB=\sqrt{(a-5)^2+b^2}≤ 10$$
which means $$(a+5)^2+b^2≤ 100 ---- (1)$$  $$(a-5)^2+b^2≤ 100 ---- (2)$$
From (1) and (2), I got $$20a≤ 0$$
I got lost from here.

Comment: Hint: Less algebra, more geometry. Think circles in the plane, and where they intersect.

Comment: This is one of those problems where sketching it on a paper -- say, one with a regular rectangular grid of, say, about $12 \times 22$ cells, so you have at least one cell of "border" around the interesting area. Draw two circles around the two points, with radius $10$ -- actually, make them half-circles, since you are only interested in the region covered by *both* circles. Don't just count the grid points for an answer; look at the grid and the figure, and consider *combinatorics*, and perhaps look into *Gauss circle problem*, and you should discover the math you need to solve this problem.

Comment: @NominalAnimal  printable graph paper, various sizes of grid squares, at http://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph

Comment: @WillJagy: Graph paper, exactly. Uh, me fail English. I prefer the one with 5mm grid without heavy index lines sold (cheap) here in Northern Europe; I've got one always handy for doodling or working out anything that occurs to me. Another possibility is to just use e.g. Inkscape (free!), and set up a suitable rectangular grid. I just find paper still a bit easier than computers, but maybe I'm just too old for this newfangled tech stuff. :)

Comment: @NominalAnimal good. That would be very close to five lines per inch, with no "index" lines, http://www.printablepaper.net/preview/grid-portrait-letter-5-noindex  Anyway, it is disturbing to see how poorly students graph. It seems that a graph is just something that appears on a computer screen, they don't do them by hand if they can avoid it.

Comment: @WillJagy: It is a pity. There are physiological reasons why using different approaches -- talking, writing, drawing, waving your hands; for some, even singing or dancing, depending on how their brain has differentiated specific tasks to different regions -- makes it *easier/possible* to mentally grasp, learn, and apply stuff. I for example recall things much better if I write key sentences by hand (doesn't work with typing). I'm more creative, if I walk and move about. Sketching stuff lets me see things (especially ratios and scales) I cannot visualize in my head correctly. It is **useful**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solution, I got 121 points, though I approached this with a predominantly logical approach.  To start, I considered all the possibilities for $XA=0$, as you would expect, under these conditions, the only solution is $X=(-5,0)$.  next, I considered all the solutions for $XA=1$, this gives 3 solutions as the $y$ value of $X(x,y)$ can be both positive and negative for the given value of $x$ at $XB=10$, giving 2 values, and $y=o$ for $XB=9$ where $x=-4$, so can only give one value, resulting in 3 values for $X$.  If you consider the next point, you get 2 possible points for $XB=10$ and for $XB=9$ and 1 possibility for $XB=8$, giving 5 total possibilities at $XB=2$.  Continuing on in this fashion gives the sequence of odd numbers defined by $\sum_{n=1}^{k}2n-1$.  As this question is bound by the greatest distance being 10, the sequence cannot be extended beyond $XA=10$, as $[0,...,10]$ is an 11 element list, $k$ can be given the value of 11 for this question, $\sum_{n=1}^{11}2n-1\\$.
$Solving \sum_{n=1}^{11}2n-1: 
\\\sum_{n=1}^{11}2n-1=2\sum_{n=1}^{11}n-\sum_{n=1}^{11}1
\\ Using\ standard\ sumations,\ this\ gives\ us:
\\2(\frac{11(11+1)}{2})-11(1)
\\132-11=121$